# why do the definite integral results not match? (Second fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus

Why do these two results not match:

1) $F(x)=\int_x^{x+2} 4t+1\,dx=\int_x^0 4t+1 \,dt+\int_0^{x+2}4t+1\,dt= (-4x+1)+(4x+8)=9$

If you substitute $x=1$, then $\int_1^3 4t+1\,dt$ is equal to $2t^2+t=18+3-3=18$.

This result does not match the previous answer of nine. Why is that? Thank you so much!

Comment: In your first calculation, you did not correctly use the fact that an antiderivative of $4t + 1$ is $2t^2 + t$.

Comment: did i do the first calculation the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You technically did not calculate wrong - you simply missed a step.

Here is what you should have done...

$F(x)=\int_x^{x+2} 4t+1\,dx=\int_x^0 4t+1 \,dt+\int_0^{x+2}4t+1\,dt= 2t^2+t|_x^0+2t^2+t|_x^{x+2}$.  This results in $-2x^2-x+2x^2+8x+8+x+2=8x+10$.  Again if you substitute $x=1$, you still get 18.  This means your results match.